# Quickest and easiest way to set up a web page to search an SQL database?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I usually only work on system admin projects and software packaging and have little knowledge of web technologies, but I've been given the task of building a simple website that searches an SQL 2005 database from the users input and lists the results. That's it.

Can anybody help me out with some sample code or some such? Since we're a pure Microsoft house, it will be running on SQL 2005 and IIS so I'm assuming I'll need to use ASP.NET, but perhaps my inexperience is leading me down the wrong path.

Any help or suggestions would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

You might want to look at [ASP.NET Dynamic Data](http://www.asp.net/dynamicdata/). This is exactly the scenario it was designed for.

Comment: @unknown (google) 

just make sure all your Foreign Keys are in place and Dynamic Data will do the rest!

Comment: Yeah!  ASP.NET Dynamic Data is awesome

Comment: Thanks guys.  Looks good.  I've got a page with my database tables listed. That's a start!